# What does f(n) and g(n) mean in this question?

Tags: asymptotics

The question I’m trying to answer is about asymptotic inequality.
The question states, 
If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials with respective leading terms $ax^{n}$ and $bx^{m}$ then $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \sim \frac{a}{b}x^{n-m}$.
I am confused what $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are here, there is no information before the question to help indicate what it could mean.

Any help in starting the answer would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a typo. The correct expression is
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \sim \frac{a}{b}x^{n-m}
$$